# Подскажите как сверстать полукруг

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как сверстать этот зеленый полукруг. Сейчас он сделан на clip-path, но у него плохая поддержка.Через border-radius выходит не то что нужно.[image: зеленый полукруг]

Comment: border-radius + абсолютное позиционирование + overflow hidden.....

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас попробую

Comment: Всё получилось. Спасибо

Comment: Написал ответ, со вторым вариантом.

Answer (score 0):

**Первый вариант**: как написал в комментарии border-radius + абсолютное позиционирование + overflow hidden.

**Второй вариант** именно для полукруга:

```css
div {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 45px;
  width: 90px;
  border-top-left-radius: 90px;
  border-top-right-radius: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Ну и его уже абсолютным позиционирование можно расположить как хотите.

Comment: Первый вариант помог, думаю на нем остановлюсь. А так спасибо за варианты!